# Async function with a loading screen

Tags: react-native, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am setting state in the constructor like this - this is for text that says "Fetching data...":

```
this.state = {
      loading: true
    }
```

Then I have an async function like this, which will get some data.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData().done()
  }

  async fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch(URL)
    const json = await response.json()
    const stars = json.stargazers_count
    this.setState({ stars })
  }
```

How do I know when I can set the isLoading state to false and hide the loading text and display the data?  I seem to be missing some piece here!

Thanks
Jordan

Comment: async/await is not part of ES7.

Comment: @FelixKling isn't it formally accepted as an ES7 proposal though? I'd say that's close enough.

Comment: @patrick: Proposals are not part of any release until they reach stage 4. ES7(ES2016) was released this year and does not contain async/await (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/).  It will be part of ES2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert `stars` in your state, you can also set isLoading to `false`

```
this.setState({ stars, isLoading: false });
```